# How to call a Control's event handler? Get EventArgs value C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to call a `OnCellEditEnding` event from another event,

```
private void BillsTableRecords_OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

My issue is I don't know how to pass the `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` into the method, i.e. the `e` in the below method obviously gives an error as it is referencing `RoutedEventArgs` not `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs`.

```
private void BillsRecordsCheckBox_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    BillsTableRecords_OnCellEditEnding(sender, e);
}
```

So how do obtain the value from `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` so that I can pass the value in the method? Please note that the `DataGrid` cell with be selected at this point so it will contain a value.

Comment: Make both events call a method with a list of required arguments that exist independently of an EventArgs or pass a `new DataGridCellEditEndingEventArg()` with the appropriate members set, or pass null.

Comment: @AlexK. I did that ,but I still need that `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` value in the method.

Comment: This is not the right way to call event from another event. you probably need to bind your checkbox to DataGrid in someway

Comment: You presumably need values in properties that DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs exposes, pass them individually.

Comment: @AlexK. How do I do that? That is what I can't work out.

Comment: Call `this.YourNewMethod(e.EditingElement, e.SomethingElse, 1234, "Anything you need");`

Comment: @AlexK. `e` in the `DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs` is a local property so you can't pass it in a different method. If I try to pass `e.something` in a method within a `RoutedEventArgs` event, it just gives an error of this, `RoutedEventArgs does not contain a definition for DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs`

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks , I figured it out. You help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this approach. Event handlers are to be called by events; their signature does not really fit for a standalone call. In case you execute business code in your event handler, it is also not good design, because your event handlers are UI code, which should be separated from business code.

The best way to go here is to create a dedicated method that does what you want and call it from both event handlers:

```
private void DoStuff(/* add the parameters you need*/) {
    //do stuff
}

private void BillsTableRecords_OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DoStuff();
}

private void BillsRecordsCheckBox_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: How do I get the `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` value when calling the `do stuff` method from `On_Checked` handler?

Comment: You are not supposed to use the `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` for a call to the method. You pass the values from the event args as parameters to your method. That way you stay independent from your event args.

Comment: if you need `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` you need to fire its Appropriate event. @KyloRen

Comment: Problem is, I need it as the check box is part of a datagrid and I need the row object so as I can update the record for that row. I tried checkbox column , but `OnCellEditEnding` fires the event on the first click and checking a checkbox requires two clicks, so even when the columns check box is checked it give you a false value as the first clich does not check the box.

Answer (score 1):

try that

```
private void BillsRecordsCheckBox_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    BillsTableRecords_OnCellEditEnding(sender, new DataGridCellEditEndingEventArg());
}
```

If you want to keep the arguments from the `RoutedEventArgs`, add them to the constructor of `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArg`